# Python Array .dot product

Tags: python, numpy

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[159], line 19
     16 iters = 10 
     18 for i in range(iters):
---> 19     w1, b1, w2, b2 = backpropagatealgorithm(w1, w2, b1, b2, p, t, alpha)

Cell In[154], line 5, in backpropagatealgorithm(w1, w2, b1, b2, p, t, alpha)
      3 def backpropagatealgorithm(w1, w2, b1, b2, p, t, alpha):
----> 5     a0, a1, a2 = forwardpropagation(w1, w2, b1, b2)
      7     #Calculate derivatives
      8     n1 = a1  

Cell In[150], line 6, in forwardpropagation(w1, b1, w2, b2)
      3 def forwardpropagation(w1, b1, w2, b2):
      5     a0 = p
----> 6     a1 = logsiglayer(np.dot(w1, p, b1))
      7     a2 = linearlayer(np.dot(w2, a1, b2))
      9     return a0 ,a1, a2

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in dot(*args, **kwargs)

# **ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)**
```

Nothing is working when it should be working I checked if they were arrays and they all are I changed dimensions but no matter what nothing works.

Comment: What did you expect, a scalar, with the size 3 dimension summing, or a (3,3) outer product?

Answer (score 1):

Let's work with a reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])   # shape is (3, 1)
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])         # shape is (3,)

print(np.dot(a, b))
# ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)
```

Let's revisit what really *is* a matrix multiplication and how it is defined:

> In mathematics, particularly in linear algebra, matrix multiplication is a binary operation that produces a matrix from two matrices. For matrix multiplication, **the number of columns in the first matrix must be equal to the number of rows in the second matrix**. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)

Therefore, let's make it happen:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1], [2], [3]])   # shape is (3, 1)
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])         # shape is (3,)

# Add a dimension to the left (it's now a row-matrix)
b = b[None, :]                  # shape is (1, 3)

print(np.dot(a, b))
# [[1 2 3]
#  [2 4 6]
#  [3 6 9]]
```